# Excessive Down voting

Tags: support

I have a stack overflow account and just now(not more than hour ago) each and every question I had ever asked or an answer I had written got down voted.

I would have understood if few of my Q and A being marked down.. but as almost all my activity is marked down I am suspecting something fishy.

I would like an explanation and/or some justification for the act? Can anyone help? Or can I at least know who I Ticked off to get a reaction like this?

Comment: Don't worry, a script runs every night that reverts this sort of thing. If whoevers doing it keeps doing it they'll have a mod to talk to

Comment: I went ahead and warned the user involved here, and if the system doesn't take care of those votes by tomorrow, flag us and we'll have a team member manually invalidate them.

Comment: thank you @BradLarson. Can I know the handle of the user responsible?

Comment: No, I don't believe that would serve any constructive purpose. I also can't reveal non-public information like that.

Comment: yes, I understand, it was just to curb my curiosity :).